# Cannot access Angular $scope variable implemented inside Electron ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I'm trying to access a $scope variable from the ipcRenderer implemented under an angular controller like this

```
angular
        .module('app',[])
        .controller('inputsController',function ($scope){

            var ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
                ipcRenderer.on('my-Response',function(event,data){
                    $scope.inputs = data;
                });
                $scope.test = 'some value';
                console.log('test value : ' + $scope.test); //prints some valuee
                console.log('inputs value : ' + $scope.inputs);// undefined
        });
```

In the html page I'm trying to access the $scope data like this:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="inputsController" class="container">
        test: {{test}}
        inputs: {{inputs}}
    </div>
</body>
```

The log results shows that the value of $scope.inputs is undefined, therefore the value is not bound in the page.

My initial thought was that since we have the $scope available from the controller(being injected as a parameter), we should be able to use it to attached values like $scope.input and then get it bound in the page.However this doesnt seem to behave as expected.

Is there anything that I am missing here or my approach of having ipc inside an angular controller is wrong ? please suggest ....

Answer (score 1):

the event field is outside of angular's scope, you can do like this:

```
var ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
            ipcRenderer.on('my-Response',function(event,data){
                $timeout(function(){
                     $scope.inputs = data;
                }, 0);
            });
```